# Bridging two networks: access to bridge slow and unreliable

Tags: network-bridge

I have a LAN that connects local computers, and in addition I have a dedicated connection to an overseas network with a static IP address assigned for my use. An ubuntu (14.04.01LTS) box with two network interfaces is connected to the LAN via eth0 and the overseas network via eth1. I got the ubuntu box to talk to computers on both networks by adding some static routes. However, I would also like other boxes on the LAN to be able to connect to the overseas network. I thought that setting up a bridge would be the way to do this. This is what I tried:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports eth0 eth1
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_waitport 0
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 1
    hostname Avery3
```

After rebooting, the LAN connection is almost, but not quite, completely unusable. I can `ping` the bridge from other boxes on the LAN without trouble. But if I try `ssh` to it, most often the connection times out. Occasionally after a long delay it will connect, and then, briefly, I have a fine ssh connection. But it always fails after a few minutes.

This works:

```
    ...
    bridge_ports eth0
    ...
```

...in that I now have a reliable LAN connection. But of course the bridge does nothing useful.

Any idea why adding the remote connection to the bridge would make LAN connections slow and unreliable? If I'm doing it all wrong (i.e., maybe a bridge is not the solution I'm looking for), how should I solve this?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: I may be wrong, and perhaps someone with greater experience will correct me.  I don't think you want to bridge the networks - they become a single network, and all traffic on one is repeated on the other.  I think instead you want to use your Ubuntu box as a router, and send directed traffic from local to overseas.  Some dated information can be found at [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router)

Comment: I did try that, but I can't get it to work. All the commands appear to work and I can see the results in my routing and ip tables, but I can't ping or ssh the overseas net from any machine other than the one that has the direct connection.

Comment: Is the overseas net a specific IP network?  The solution on an individual machine would be to add the route from that machine, through the gateway (the Ubuntu box) to the overseas network, or to configure the router (Ubuntu box) to advertise the route, and the other machines to look for advertised routes (RIP protocol)

Comment: OK, so how do I do those things? I tried the first, and it didn't work, which presumably means I did it wrong. I don't know how to configure the gateway to advertise the route.

Comment: You need to talk to the admin of the oversees network, because he's bound to have firewalled off the connections on his side. (At least: that's what I would do)  >:)

Comment: @Fabby: The problem with that idea is that I have no trouble connecting to the overseas network from the ubuntu box.

Comment: Yes, off course!  The box itself isn't firewalled, but the other addresses are!  (Every TCP packet contains the originator, even when forwarded over a router and certainly a bridge!)  We should take this up in chat, but unfortunately your reputation+my reputation are too low to do this...

Comment: OK, I guess I don't understand enough about firewalls for that to make any sense to me. But it sounds like the endeavor is hopeless, and I should just content myself with ssh tunnels.